# Socket creation failed -- TBB unable to start Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, socks, client

I tried to start Tor in a computer pool and it failed. The PCs were running Windows 7. I downloaded the latest Tor Browser Bundle and executed the start script. Almost immediately a warning appeared the Tor could not bet started. In the log file I found the following lines:

```
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Notice] Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-17c24b3118224d65) running on Windows 7.
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Notice] Read configuration file "[..]\torrc".
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Warning] Warning from libevent: evsig_init: socketpair: Invalid argument [WSAEINVAL ]
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.21-stable using method win32. Good.
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Warning] Socket creation failed: Invalid argument [WSAEINVAL ]
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Warning] Socket creation failed: Invalid argument [WSAEINVAL ]
Okt 17 10:51:57.483 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

It seems that some local policy prevented Tor from opening ports 9150 and 9151. I tried some other random ports (between 1024 and 65535) none of them worked. Is it possible to use Tor on those machines? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

You can try out commenting all SocksPorts and ControlPorts, then setting `SocksPort 0` and `ControlPort 0` in torrc. When Tor is able to connect, then there is a chance, although it requires programming skills. Socks is just an interface for browsers (TBB's Firefox) to communicate with Tor. If you (or pay someone) could teach Tor and Firefox to communicate using another interface (inter process communication), it could work (something like the [LibOnionRoute](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2013-May/004801.html) Tor library). Otherwise the answer is probably no.

Comment: do you thought about www.onionroute.org? The website doesn't load for me.

Comment: Yes. Edited my post. Not sure what happened to it. Although that would be another good question.